# ruby .gsub replace/substitute a specific range of indexes

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, gsub, substitution

Ruby newbie here. I'm trying to create a method that 'corrects' titles of movies. The methods should capitalize properly, ignore capitalizing articles(a, an, the, of) unless at the beginning, and should correct properly even if the title given is all uppercase or jumbled. I get stuck when I want to specify a certain range of indexes in a string (1..100) to find articles and change them into lowercase. The first half of my code runs just fine, but the second half which modifies a range of indexes the .join is where i'm having trouble. If its possible to use .gsub's or 'if' statements after the ".join" that would be the best advice for my level of understanding. I hope I'm being clear. Any help/input is appreciated. Thank you

```
class Title
  attr_accessor :title
  def initialize(title)
    @title = title
  end

  def fix
    new_array = []
    @title.split.each do |word|
      new_array << "#{word}".capitalize
    end
    new_array.join(" ")
      new_array(1..100).gsub("Of","of").gsub("The","the").gsub("And","and")
    end
  end
end
```

alternately:

```
class Title
  attr_accessor :title
  def initialize(title)
    @title = title
  end

  def fix
    new_array = []
    @title.split.each do |word|
      new_array << "#{word}".capitalize
    end
    new_array.join(" ")
    if new_array(1..100) then
      new_array.gsub("Of","of").gsub("The","the").gsub("And","and")
    end
  end
end
```

here are the specs

```
describe "Title" do
  describe "fix" do
    it "capitalizes the first letter of each word" do
      expect( Title.new("the great gatsby").fix ).to eq("The Great Gatsby")
    end
    it "works for words with mixed cases" do
      expect( Title.new("liTTle reD Riding hOOD").fix ).to eq("Little Red Riding Hood")
    end
    it "downcases articles" do
      expect( Title.new("The lord of the rings").fix ).to eq("The Lord of the Rings")
      expect( Title.new("The sword And The stone").fix ).to eq("The Sword and the Stone")
      expect( Title.new("the portrait of a lady").fix ).to eq("The Portrait of a Lady")
    end
    it "works for strings with all uppercase characters" do
      expect( Title.new("THE SWORD AND THE STONE").fix ).to eq("The Sword and the Stone")
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's one approach to solving your issue. I'd like to suggest an alternative for consideration. You are seeking to capitalize any instance of an article in your title except if that instance is at the beginning of the title. You can handle the second part of that by using `.each_with_index`. For the first part, you can create an array of the target words and then search for the word in the target array like so:

```
def fix
  articles = ["a", "and", "the", "of"]

  word_array = title.downcase.split(" ")
  new_array = []

  word_array.each_with_index do |word, index|
    if index == 0 || !articles.include?(word)
      new_array << word.capitalize
    else
      new_array << word
    end
  end
  new_array.join(" ")
end
```

So `.downcase` will "normalize" your title so all the words are lowercase. `.split(" ")` will turn your string into an array of words (cutting at every space). You'll then visit every element of that array using `.each_with_index`. This method gives you access to the element and the index. You can then check whether you are at index 0 OR the negation of whether this particular element is an article. `.includes?` checks if the argument passed to it is an element of the array it is being called on. It returns `true` or `false` based on if it is or not. With `!` before it, we are negating the result (turning true into false and false into true) because we only care if the word is NOT in the array. At the end, we are calling `.join(" ") to deliver a string separating every word with a space as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Use String#slice like this:

```
string[0..99]
```

Example usage:

```
string = "Everything"
string[5..8]
=> "thin"
```

Ruby also has good ways to accomplish your goal:

```
stopwords = %w{ a an and but in of on or the }.to_set
title.capitalize.split.map{|word| 
  stopwords.include?(word) ? word : word.capitalize
}.join(" ")
```

Comment: i replaced the parenthesis with brackets to get the index range but i'm running a syntax error now. not sure how to integrate the code after the .join portion.